# Split lists in vectors in R

Tags: r

I have many lists in R whit the structure like:

```
>lists <- list(a = letters[1:6], b = letters[7:13], c = letters[14:25])   

>lists
$a
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"

$b
[1] "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m"

$c
[1] "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y"
```

And I want to split in n vectors to get:

```
>a
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
>b
[1] "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m"
>c
[1] "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" “y"
```

Thx

Comment: Sorry, your question is hard to understand. Is it a programming question? If so, it probably belongs in StackOverflow. Veo que eres de Mexico. Dime si necesitas ayuda entendiendo como funciona el sitio. In English: I noticed you are from Mexico. Let me know if you need help figuring out how this site works.

Comment: Try `list2env(lists, globalenv())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `list2env`

```
list2env(lists, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```